# unable to obtain buddypress user avatar url

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I am working on a plugin, inside the plugin, I have made a Javascript file in which I want to have the specific user BuddyPress avatar URL assigned to a variable.

My javascript file inside the plugin folder is named: myscript.js.php (so PHP can be executed inside this file).

The code inside the javascript file:

```
<?php
   header('Content-type: text/javascript');

   $home_dir = preg_replace('^wp-content/plugins/[a-z0-9\-/]+^', '', getcwd());
   include($home_dir . 'wp-load.php');

   $ucurrentid = $current_user->ID;
   $member_id = bp_core_get_userid( $ucurrentid );
   $uphoto = bp_core_fetch_avatar ( array( 
       'item_id' =>$ member_id,'html'=>false 
   ) );
?>

var uid = <?php echo $current_user->ID ?>;
var uphoto = <?php echo $uphoto ?>;

alert(uphoto);
```

This return the error :
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function  bp_user_avatar()

Why is the function undefined, which BuddyPress file should I include into the code so the function works?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

http://viviendoenlaeradelaweb20.blogspot.com/2013/03/buddypress-avatar-url.html

I hope will be useful :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can try :

```
$avatar_link = bp_core_fetch_avatar(array('html' =>  false, 'item_id' =>  $user_id));
$avatar = '<img title="admin" src="' . $avatar_link . '"></img>';

// Display image
echo $avatar
```

You need user ID. Inside loop, you can do :

```
$user_id = bp_get_member_user_id();
```